# Can't get any FactoryGirl factories to register

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to set up Rspec and FactoryGirl on an existing Rails 3 project which previously has had no automated testing.

The error I'm getting when running the test as below is `Factory not registered: admin`

I can't see why this would be failing, it happens for every test through my specs that use a factory.

**/Gemfile.rb** (concatenated for brevity)

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails
end
```

**/config/application.rb** (concatenated for brevity)

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec, fixture: true
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: "spec/factories"
end
```

**/spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/mechanize'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

HTTPI.log = false

FactoryGirl.factories.clear

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, type: :controller
end
```

**/spec/support/controller_macros.rb**

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
    end
  end
end
```

**/spec/factories/users.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin do
    sequence(:email) {|n| "user#{n}@local.test"}
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    association :user_role, factory: :admin_role

    trait :as_reseller do
      association :user_role, factory: :reseller_role
    end

    trait :as_customer do
      association :user_role, factory: :customer_role
    end
  end

  factory :reseller, parent: :admin do
    as_reseller
  end

  factory :customer, parent: :admin do
    as_customer
  end
end
```

**/spec/controllers/accounts_controller_spec.rb**

```
describe AccountCodesController do
  describe "as administrator" do
    login_admin

    describe "GET 'index'" do
      it "returns http success" do
        get 'index'
        response.should be_success
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `FactoryGirl.factories.clear` confuse me a lot.

According to [doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) you needn't do any spec_helper modification (if you use it in Rails app and through Bundle).

This is my [spec_helper](https://gist.github.com/gotva/7734835) in one of my APP and I use factories in it successfully.

Comment: Don't know where I got that line from... found it in another spec_helper.rb and added it when I was trying to fix a different issue. More to go still, but this at least fixed the problem in this question. Thanks =]

Answer (score 0):

It's explain on the link

The stable documentation is here :

http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/tree/1.3.x

Comment: In the first few lines of that documentation it says `If you want to use factory_girl with Rails 3, use the factory_girl_rails gem, not this one.`, which I am doing. 

Also, the documentation linked is for version 1.3.x. From my `Gemfile.lock` I can see that the version of factory_girl in use as included by factory_girl_rails is 4.2.0.